# Problems with translation

Tags: translation

> 僕が、君に何をしたっていうんだい?

I have trouble placing the 僕が, also I'm not 100% sure what したってい means here.

> わたし、クラシックはさっぱりだから…

I know that わたし means 'me' but when I translated the sentence it didn't seem to fit there.

Comment: Please ask one question per question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 「[僕]{ぼく}が、[君]{きみ}に[何]{なに}をしたっていうんだい？ 」

First, try pairing up the verbs and the persons (action-takers).

You should have:

1) 僕 and した

2) 君 and いう（言う）

The sentence means:

> "What are you saying (that) I did/I've done to you?"

**IMPORTANT**: Note that the subject of this sentence is the ***unmentioned*** 「**君**」, and not the 「君」 in 「君に」.  If you thought it was 「僕」, you would not understand this sentence at all.

Moving on...

> 「わたし、クラシックはさっぱりだから・・・。」

Without any context given by OP, I take this sentence to be about classical music.

> "As for me, I have no knowledge of classical music, so..." or
>
> "As for me, I do not like classical music at all, so..."

The key word here is 「さっぱり」, which means "not at all".